# How to start the introduction from the first page in article in two column

Tags: two-column

I've tried to start the introduction from the first page but I don't why started from the second page. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}

\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}
\usepackage{citesort}
%% \usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}

\newcommand{\BibTeX}{Bib\TeX}
\newcommand{\REVTeX}{REV\TeX}

\sloppy 

\begin{document}
\title[Author guidelines]{How to prepare and submit an article for publication in an IOP Publishing journal using \LaTeXe}

\author{Content \& Services Team}

\address{IOP Publishing, Temple Circus, Temple Way, Bristol BS1 6HG, UK}

\ead{submissions@iop.org}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{indented}

    \item[]February 2014

\end{indented}

\begin{abstract}

    This section contains the abstract.

\end{abstract}

\ioptwocol
\section{Introduction}

The \texttt{iopart-num} \BibTeX{} style is intended for use in
preparing manuscripts for Institute of Physics Publishing journals,
including Journal of Physics.  It provides numeric citation with
Harvard-like formatting, based upon the specification in ``How to
prepare and submit an article for publication in an IOP journal using Latex.


\section{Examples}

The entries in the reference list below provide examples of the
formatting of various types of references, of varying complexity,
including journal articles, articles in proceedings or collections,
books (individual, multivolume, or in a series), theses, and
unpublished references. 


\section*{References}
\bibliography{iopart-num}

\end{document}
```

The command for two columns is:

```
\ioptwocol
```

Comment: Hi, where can i get `iopart.cls` and related files?

Comment: On this link:

http://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/iopart-num/

Comment: Yeah, that one comes with TeX Live and MikTeX. We all have it :-) But what about the class file and its `clo` files?

Comment: I am so sorry :( Here is the class file:


https://www.dropbox.com/s/27qp67xvzcif9i6/iopart.cls?dl=0

Comment: That behaviour is hard-coded in the class. I am not sure if the title should be typeset in two-col mode as  well. I would ask the editors for advice on that matter.